How transfer data from a child component to its parent in C# Blazor using an input element?
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to utilize a reusable input component for creating a new user profile. When I try to create a new user, all the data entered into the reusable component appears empty. I suspect this is due to a problem with passing data from the child component to the parent. Interestingly, when I use the standard  tag, everything works fine. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Main page
AddProfile.razor
<form> 
       <div class="col-md-6">
                <Label LabelClass="small mb-1"  LabelText="@Loc[nameof(ResourcesEnum.GeneralFirstName)]"/>
                <Input InputPlaceholder="@Loc[nameof(ResourcesEnum.GeneralEnterFirstName)]" BindValue="@_contact.FirstName" InputClass="form-control" />
            </div>

        ...

    <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <Button BtnClass="btn btn-primary" IconClass="bi bi-plus-lg" OnClick="Submit" />
        <Button BtnClass="btn btn-danger" IconClass="bi bi-x-circle" OnClick="() => CancelModalWindow()" DataToggle="modal" DataTarget="#exampleModal"/>
    </div>
    </form>

@code {

    private ContactDTO _contact = new ContactDTO();
    private List<PartnerDTO>? _partners = new List<PartnerDTO>();
    private bool _switchAddPartner = false;
    private ModalBootstrap? _modalComponent;
    private string? _returnUrl;
    private string _submitText = "Save contact";
    private string _exam;
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _partners = (await PartnerService.GetAllPartners())?.ToList();
        var uri = NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavigationManager.Uri);
        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("returnUrl", out var url))
        {
            _returnUrl = url!;
            _submitText = "Save and return";
        }
    }
    
    void HandleInputValueChanged(string value)
    {
        // Update the input value in the parent component
        _contact.FirstName = value;
    }
    
    private void HandleInputData(string inputValue)
    {
        _contact.FirstName = inputValue;
        Console.WriteLine($"it is value input: {_contact.FirstName}!!!!!");
    }
    
    private void NavigateUrlContactsPage()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/contacts");
    }
    
    private void Cancel()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_returnUrl))
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo(_returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            NavigateUrlContactsPage();
        }
    }
    
    private async Task Submit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Before Submit: {_contact.FirstName}");
        try
        {
            var createdContact = await ContactService.CreateContactAsync(_contact);
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_returnUrl))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(createdContact.FirstName);
                var returnUrlWithNewContact = $"{_returnUrl}?newContactId={createdContact.Id}";
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo(returnUrlWithNewContact);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error{_contact.FirstName}");
                NavigateUrlContactsPage();
            }
            Snackbar.Add($"\u2795 {_contact.FullName}", Severity.Success);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Snackbar.Add($"{@Loc[nameof(ResourcesEnum.GeneralError)]}: {ex.Message}", Severity.Error);
        }
    }
    
    private void CancelModalWindow()
    {
        _modalComponent.ShowModal($"{@Loc[nameof(ResourcesEnum.GeneralConfirmExit)]}", $"{@Loc[nameof(ResourcesEnum.GeneralConfirmExitQuestion)]}",()=>Cancel() );
    }

}

Input.razor (reusable component)
<input class="@InputClass" type="@InputType" placeholder="@InputPlaceholder" @bind="@BindValue"/>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string InputType { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string InputClass { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string InputPlaceholder { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string BindValue { get; set; }
}


Search blazor custom input for any number of resources that show you how to bind correctly.  You can alkso review the standard InputText code to see how that's done - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs

I recreated yours component and I hope everything works fine.
Below is my CInput. I only changed Bindings to work correctly. In blazor @bind-SomeValue is simplified syntax to handle 2 separate Parameters. One is Value to pass, and another is value to recieve by EventCallback. To make it work Both Parameters must have the same name but EventCallback needs to have 'Changed' word added at the end. When I use it string is passed both ways. If it was not your problem give more feedback.
<input class="@ParamInputClass" type="@ParamInputType" placeholder="@ParamInputPlaceholder" value="@ParamBindValue" @onchange="OnValueChanged" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string ParamInputType  { get; set; } = "text";
    [Parameter] public string ParamInputClass { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string ParamInputPlaceholder { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter] public string ParamBindValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ParamBindValueChanged { get; set; }

    protected async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs? val)
    {
        if (val is null || val.Value is null) { return; }
        string ConvertedToString = ((string) val.Value) ?? string.Empty ;
        // Add whatever logic here or even some validation if not using fluent validation on form
        await ParamBindValueChanged.InvokeAsync(ConvertedToString);
    }
}

And here is the component that is using it.
<CInput ParamInputType="text" ParamInputPlaceholder="Some Text" ParamInputClass="fs-3"   @bind-ParamBindValue="@Text" />

<div>
    @Text
</div>

@code {
    string Text = "Start value";
}


it helped me a lot and it worked for me. Can you explain what happens in the OnValueChanged function?

onchange is a EventCallback so I either need to have that type of an object that binds to it or a method with correct signature. Unfortunately returned value is an object so I have to make conversion.  First lines are just checks to eliminate warnings.  However because you choose you input type by Parameter value could be int, datetime or in any other format. Therefore you need to make changes to OnValueChanged method to check which type value is. I do not know what you want to accomplish, but maybe using generics in razor component could be a better idea.
